# What do i need to do to have wifi with a E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, atheros, lan

This is my first post.

Yes i checked all other posts on Askubuntu with similar problem but nothing seemed to work for 2021.
Answers are outdated and links dont work. I want my network card on my motherboard to find wifi. So i probably need some drivers for my type of kernel. I tried to install previous kernels but nothing seemed to work.

My kernel is 5.8.0-55-generic.
Output of lshw -C network is

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 13
   serial: d8:cb:8a:a4:13:89
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.8.0-55-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:18 memory:ef100000-ef13ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev d0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H97 Chipset LPC Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
```

I also found this [https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1969-e091-1462-7918][1],
which is a kernel driver but i tried to compile the file with gcc and errors for header files appear all the way, because gcc looks in the wrong folder for including them.

Any help for your Linux brother, me, would be appreciated!

PS. If you need any other outputs i will edit the question and paste it there.

Comment: Ethernet is for a wired network, and I’m not seeing a wireless device in your `lshw` output. Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci`? If you have a built-in wireless adapter, it may appear in there.

Comment: Then i guess i have judged incorectly on that manner. Hes is my lspci output

Comment: I currently use a usb wifi adapter to find wifi, but i would really like to find another way to connect, but i guess i don't have any ways to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a LAN Controller, which does not support W-LAN. Please Link or Name your exact Controller (or Motherboard), since I can't find any information about it.

Comment: [link](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H97-GAMING-3/Specification) Yeah you are right @tweimann. It say LAN not WLAN